# Disabled then enabled buttons, disabled is false but on the page they are still disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

On page load I disable a few button using jQuery .prop() like so:

```
<body onload="bodyLoaded();">
  $( "#show" ).prop("disabled",true);
  $( "#update" ).prop("disabled",true);
  $( "#comebacktothisone" ).prop("disabled",true);
  $( "#review" ).prop("disabled",true);
```

Then when one of two other buttons is pressed I want to enable those previously disabled buttons, this is in the onclick function so I only want to set the disabled property back to false once, not every time they click. The console.log appears so I know the if statement works. However the buttons remain disabled:

```
if($( "#show" ).prop("disabled")){
           console.log("enabled it");
            $( "#show" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#update" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#comebacktothisone" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#review" ).prop("disabled",false);
       }
```

I tried this too:

```
       console.log("enable it ");
        $( "#show" ).prop("disabled",false);
        $("#show").attr("disabled",false);
        $( "#update" ).prop("disabled",false);
        $( "#comebacktothisone" ).prop("disabled",false);
        $( "#review" ).prop("disabled",false);
```

... the buttons are still gray and inert. Whats going on ?

Edit:

```
var savedQuestions = [];
var answerShown = false;

$( document ).ready(function(){

   console.log('here we go ');

     $( "#nailedit" ).click(function(){
       $.get("QuestionPage",{name:"next",result:"nailed"},function(responseJSON){

           //set the question and category texts
           $("#cardArea").val(responseJSON["card"]);
           $( "#cat"  ).text(responseJSON["category"]);
           $( "#cardid" ).text(responseJSON["flashCardnum"]);

           //clear answer field after every 'next'...
           $( "#answerArea" ).val("");

           //set the click function of show button to show the answer..
           $( "#show" ).click(function() {
                $( "#answerArea" ).val(responseJSON["answer"]); 
                answerShown = true;
            });
       });

       answerShown = false;
       if($( "#show" ).prop("disabled")){
           console.log("enabled it");
            $( "#show" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#show" ).removeAttr('disabled');
            $( "#update" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#comebacktothisone" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#review" ).prop("disabled",false);
       }
   });

   $( "#missedit" ).click(function() {
       $.get("QuestionPage",{name:"next",result:"missed"},function(responseJSON){

           //set the question and category texts
           $("#cardArea").val(responseJSON["card"]);
           $( "#cat"  ).text(responseJSON["category"]);
           $( "#cardid" ).text(responseJSON["flashCardnum"]);

           //clear answer field after every 'next'...
           $( "#answerArea" ).val("");

           //set the click function of show button to show the answer..
           $( "#show" ).click(function() {
                $( "#answerArea" ).val(responseJSON["answer"]); 
                answerShown = true;
            });
       });

       answerShown = false;
       if($( "#show" ).prop("disabled")){
           console.log("enable it ");
            $( "#show" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#show" ).removeAttr('disabled');
            $( "#update" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#comebacktothisone" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#review" ).prop("disabled",false);
       }

   });

  function bodyLoaded() {         
      $( "#show" ).prop("disabled",true);
      $( "#update" ).prop("disabled",true);
      $( "#comebacktothisone" ).prop("disabled",true);
      $( "#review" ).prop("disabled",true);
    }
```

Comment: You should always insert all of your jQuery code within a `$(document).ready(function() { [all of your code] });` block... Are you doing this?

Comment: And of course, include the jquery JS file within in your `<script>` tags, just before the end of the `<body>`

Comment: Your code looks good and should work usually. Can you please check in the console that whether $('#show') is retrieving element properly or not?

Comment: all the code is in .ready(){} and the script is there the rest of the file works just fine.

Comment: Where do I llook for that John Wink ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery ui was confusing me,
I did this instead which was much more simple:

```
.maxs-button-disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}

if($( "#show" ).hasClass("maxs-button-disabled")){
           $( "#show" ).removeClass("maxs-button-disabled");
           $( "#update" ).removeClass("maxs-button-disabled");
           $( "#comebacktothisone" ).removeClass("maxs-button-disabled");
           $( "#review" ).removeClass("maxs-button-disabled");
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$( "#show" ).removeAttr('disabled');
// for all the elements
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are implementing the part of taking the buttons back to be enabled but it seems to work just fine, compare what you are doing with this snippet to see if it helps you locate the problem, hope it helps

```js
function bodyLoaded(){
  $( "#show" ).prop("disabled",true);
  $( "#update" ).prop("disabled",true);
  $( "#comebacktothisone" ).prop("disabled",true);
  $( "#review" ).prop("disabled",true);
}

$('#someotherbutton').click(function(){
  if($( "#show" ).prop("disabled")){
           console.log("enabled it");
            $( "#show" ).prop("disabled",false);
            
            $( "#update" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#comebacktothisone" ).prop("disabled",false);
            $( "#review" ).prop("disabled",false);
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="bodyLoaded();">
<button id="show">show</button>
<button id="update">update</button>
<button id="comebacktothisone">comebacktothisone</button>
<button id="review">review</button>
<button id="someotherbutton">someotherbutton</button>

</body>
```

Comment: They are not <input>'s they are <button>'s what could that mean ?